# LibreOffice freezes after clicking "Tools-Options-LibreOffice-View"

Tags: linux, freeze, crash, libreoffice, mate

Linux Mint, MATE.

I decided to re-install LibreOffice (it was installed with Linux) because I wanted to update its version. I installed it via apt-get. After it Libreoffice starts to hang after clicking `Tools - Options - LibreOffice - View`.

Also if I delete `libreoffice-gnome`, Libreoffice just crashes after clicking it.

What's the problem?

Comment: It's not supposed to do that, which means something is wrong. Unfortunately, there is nothing diagnostic about the symptom, so people here will only be able to guess. Did you download it from the Mint repository and let the package manager install it? In the process, did it advise you that additional packages were required, and if so, did you accept them? Why did you reinstall? Was it previously working? Did it stop working after installing or updating something? Have you tried downloading it directly from LibreOffice (if there are dependency issues, that should be completely self-contained)?

Comment: Works fine for me on 5.1.6.2 but I'm on KDE. Deleting random parts of packages won't help. Many apps with problems on GTK3 can be forced to use GTK2. For [what I see for LO](https://askubuntu.com/questions/765950/force-libreoffice-5-1-2-2-to-use-gtk2-instead-of-gtk3) this depends on the installation of `libreoffice-gtk3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I've found the answer. I installed several themes (`libreoffice-style-[somestyle]`), and after this LibreOffice opened with the Tango theme and it allowed me to go to the `View` menu.